# how to create whitelist in a bloomfilter?

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

When I want to use bloomfilter in my program, there some false positive rate in it.I don't know how to create a whiltelist for these words which will be misjudgment?Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Don't you mean a blacklist? A bloom filter gives false *positives*, i.e. stuff comes through that shouldn't.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Create a **black**-list to eliminate **all** false positives? ... which would be largely pointless as it would eliminate the advantage of using a bloom filter. You may as well use a hash-map then.

Answer (score 2):

If you can restrict the space of possible queries that may be made to the Bloom Filter, you can create such a list after your entries have been hashed into the Bloom Filter.  The idea is if you know all the possible queries in advance, and the size of that set is reasonably small, you can make all these queries and save all the false positive "yes" answers along with the Bloom Filter in order to know to avoid them during your run.  A recent bioinformatics article did exactly that: http://minia.genouest.org/files/minia.pdf.

Of course, this depends on taking advantage of some property of your hashed object.  In the linked to case it is knowing that entries are overlapping DNA k-mers and thus their extensions can only have one of 4 possible values at each end.